# What is the ibrav value of a rhombohedral structure?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, crystallography, quantum-computing

I have a rhombohedral structure

[image]

The SYSTEM and CELL_PARAMETERS blocks looks like this:

```
&SYSTEM
  ibrav = 0
  A =  6.058435171
```

```
CELL_PARAMETERS {alat}
   0.494845678   0.494845678   0.000000000
   0.494845678  -0.000000000   0.494845678
   0.000000000   0.494845678   0.494845678
```

What's the right value of ibrav that I should use and what are the changes that I should make in my input file to save the same structure?
I also already checked https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm224 but I couldn't find it

Comment: You set the ibrav value for the original cell. In this case it is FCC, so ibrav would be equal to 2.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 1000!

Comment: @HemanthHaridas if I have to set the ibrav of conventional cell which is 2 I have to use the lattice parameter of conventional cell, which I don't know yet. I want to use xcrysden to find the lattice parameter of conventional cell that's why I wanted ibrav of primitive cell

Comment: @NikeDattani Thank you so much. I'm happy to belong to such amazing community :D

Comment: @Camilla there are not two different type of input files for primitive and conventional cells. You simply set ibrav=2. The scaling factor 0.5 is already implemented inside ibrav=2. So no need to worry about the specific cell_parameters you got here.

Comment: ibrav=5 for a rhombohedral structure, ibrav=2 for the FCC corresponding to your CELL_PARAMETERS.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin  But in the input file I have the lattice parameter of primitive unit cell  A =  6.058435171× 0.494845678=2.99799046 Ang . When I use that with ibrav=2 xcrysden display a structure with big atoms like the one I shared in the chat room. It's like you are telling to xcrysden that 2.99799046 Ang is the lattice parameter of conventional cell

Comment: @Camilla Not really. You don't have the lattice parameter of the primitive unit cell in your input file. When you set ibrav=2, QE assumes an FCC structure with lattice vectors: v1 = (a/2)(-1,0,1),  v2 = (a/2)(0,1,1), v3 = (a/2)(-1,1,0). So when you use ibrav=2, it shouldn't be A=2.99799046 Ang. It should be A=6.058435171 Ang to let QE know that the primitive unit cell has a unit cell length of A=2.99799046 Ang

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin Actually there is something that I don't get here. Did I mention that this input file is made with the optimized structure (The one obtained from 'vc-relax' output) that's why I see that it's not logic that A=6.058435171 Ang is lattice parameter of conventional cell, because this value is experimental and after calculation normally it should change a little bit.

Comment: @Camilla if you want to see the relaxed structure, then first change the output file as mentioned. Then do the calculation. Then open the output file. Now you are opening the input file.

Comment: @Camilla could you provide, in _some_ format, the structure you would like to enter into Quantum ESPRESSO? Once it is clear what exactly you would like to represent, the corresponding input file should be straightforward